# I'm trying to use jquery to hide any row in a table that has a negative dollar amount

Tags: jquery

I have the following table row in a table. I'm trying to use jquery to hide any row in a table that has a negative dollar amount. How can I test if the text in a div has a negative number, and how do I add the class to the row class so I can hide it.

```
<tr class="Cont">
        <td>Name of something</td>
        <td><div class="negMoney">$-1,000.22</div></td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: I suggest that you do a little research, make an attempt, and then let us know what you tried and where specifically you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `has` and `contains` selectors in jQuery.

```js
$("tr:has(div:contains('-'))").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="Cont">
        <td>Name of something a</td>
        <td><div class="negMoney">$-1,000.22</div></td>

   </tr>
  <tr class="Cont">
        <td>Name of something b</td>
        <td><div class="negMoney">$1,000.22</div></td>

   </tr>
  <tr class="Cont">
        <td>Name of something c</td>
        <td><div class="negMoney">$-1,000.22</div></td>

   </tr>
  <tr class="Cont">
        <td>Name of something d</td>
        <td><div class="negMoney">$1,000.22</div></td>

   </tr>
  <tr class="Cont">
        <td>Name of something e</td>
        <td><div class="negMoney">$1,000.22</div></td>

   </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks I was missing the div:contains('-')

Comment: Wouldn't you have a side effect with that where any <tr> that also has a <div> in it will be hidden if the contents of that div has a - anywhere in it?   Such as <tr><td><div class="title">My  Title - Sub Title</div></td></tr>

Comment: Yes, I added the div class name instead of just tr.

Answer (score 0):

`$("tr:has(div:contains('-'))").hide();`  will search **- (negative)** in each DIV of TD and then this solution will not work if any div comes in TD in future.

In below solution it will search negative value only in **negMoney** class which is 2nd TD of row.

```
$(".negMoney").each(function(i){
   var val = $(this).html();
   var isNegative = Number((val.substr(1)).replace(/\,/g,'')) < 0;       
   if(isNegative) { 
      $("tr:eq( "+ i +" )").hide(); 
   }
});
```